# How to add total amount from list of lists using Java stream api?

Tags: java, lambda, stream

I have a class:

```java
public class Customer{
private List<Order> orders;
private String name;
...
}
```

```java
public class Order{
private long orderId;
private String customerId;
private double amount;
...
}
```

---

```
public class CustomerService{

@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepo;

List<Customer> custList = customerRepo.findAllCustomers();

double amount = custList.stream().map(c -> {
return c.getOrders().stream().mapToDouble(o -> o.getAmount()).sum()}).findAny().get();

}
```

So I tried as like above in CustomerService. But the amount returned is only for the first item in the list. So in the same way how can I write to get the total amount of all the orders for that customer?

Any suggestions/input will be helpful.

Note: Sorry for any compile errors. I cannot copy my code and so I need to write in the question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
double total = custList.stream()
        .flatMap(c -> c.getOrders().stream())
        .mapToDouble(Order::getAmount)
        .sum();
```

Also note the use of *method reference* to get the amount from the order.